# Bootstrap carousel scaling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I stretch a Bootstrap carousel it zooms the top of the image. How to make it zoom the center like MasterSlider does?

My default carousel:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="/img/carousel/reception.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="/img/carousel/office.jpg" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="/img/carousel/restroom.jpg" alt="Third slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

If it was Photoshop I would call it a zoom anchor point or something like that.
I hope this is clear:

[have no rep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RbSi.png)

Comment: Can you provide snippet or link to codepen example, please?

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk  sure https://codepen.io/axelfriman/pen/aboWGyM

Comment: How do you "stretch"? some CSS property?

Comment: @AkberIqbal By stretching I meant resizing a browser window. Sorry for confusing